# How to arrange object properties to parameters in function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Lets suppose we have function with parameters:

```
function do(classId: number, schoolId: number, pupilId: number, teacherId: number, roomId: number) {
}
```

I need to call this function passing object with properties that should fill corresponding function's parameters like:

**Case one:**

```
let obj1 = {classId: 1, roomId: 3}; 

do(obj1); // passed only classId, roomId
```

**Case two:**

```
let obj2 = {schoolId: 5, pupilId: 4}; 

do(obj2); // passed only schoolId, pupilId
```

Comment: Take an object as parameter I guess, or am I overseeing something?

Comment: The problem is that object keys don't have a determined order. In *most* cases they probably list in the same order they appear on your screen, but that's not a guarantee.

Comment: The order does not matter, just go for an object with optional properties and then evaluate which ones are set in the function. There is no reason to have an order

Comment: Sure, I can pass any set of properties

Comment: Are you asking: how can I make the specific `do()` function accept an object *instead* of a list of parameters?  Or are you asking: how can I make the specific `do()` function accept *either* an object *or* a list of parameters?  Or are you asking: given a function which accepts a list of parameters, how can I transform it generically to a different function which accepts an object?

Comment: maybe you have to check with `typeof` inside your `do` function if it's getting an object and extract object properties if the result is true?

Comment: @Marv The order does matter for the function as posted... yes, change the function to take an object and the question as stated is basically obsolete. The question actually isn't really clear, jcalz's clarifying questions need to be answered...

Comment: @Aaron that is the answer to the question. In his two examples, he is passing an object to the function, so taking an object as the functions argument is what needs to be done here.

Comment: @Marv That's really not clear to me, it looked to me like the example is placeholder code, not what he actually wants (the comment describe a behavior that isn't possible with the code posted), but maybe I'm being obtuse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you want this:

```
const Do: (
    arg: {
        classId?: number;
        schoolId?: number;
        pupilId?: number;
        teacherId?: number;
        roomId?: number;
    }
) => any = ({ classId, schoolId, pupilId, teacherId, roomId }) => {};
```

I replaced the list of parameters to a single parameter, that is an [object destructuring pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Note, that you cannot use `do` as an identifier name, so I changed it to `Do`.

Also classic JS functions are not very friendly with types and typescript, so I rewrote it using an arrow function.

[The playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20obj1%20%3D%20%7BclassId%3A%201%2C%20roomId%3A%203%7D%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20obj2%20%3D%20%7BschoolId%3A%205%2C%20pupilId%3A%204%7D%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20Do%3A%20(arg%3A%20%7BclassId%3F%3A%20number%2C%20schoolId%3F%3A%20number%2C%20pupilId%3F%3A%20number%2C%20teacherId%3F%3A%20number%2C%20roomId%3F%3A%20number%7D)%20%3D%3E%20any%20%0D%0A%3D%20(%7BclassId%2C%20schoolId%2C%20pupilId%2C%20teacherId%2C%20roomId%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ADo(obj1)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0ADo(obj2)%0D%0A)

Comment: This won't work since the parameters are not optional.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz Can you explain? There is no "parameters", there is a single parameter, which is not optional, but I don't see a problem.

Comment: Typescript will complain that the function call does not meet the required parameter count. You can fix this by appending `?` to the parameters. But then the whole function makes no sense since you would need to check if the parameter is present. Overall this question is not that great

Comment: Can you share example online?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Did you try to call the function?

Comment: @OPV sure http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20obj1%20%3D%20%7BclassId%3A%201%2C%20roomId%3A%203%7D%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20obj2%20%3D%20%7BschoolId%3A%205%2C%20pupilId%3A%204%7D%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20Do%3A%20(arg%3A%20%7BclassId%3F%3A%20number%2C%20schoolId%3F%3A%20number%2C%20pupilId%3F%3A%20number%2C%20teacherId%3F%3A%20number%2C%20roomId%3F%3A%20number%7D)%20%3D%3E%20any%20%0D%0A%3D%20(%7BclassId%2C%20schoolId%2C%20pupilId%2C%20teacherId%2C%20roomId%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ADo(obj1)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0ADo(obj2)%0D%0A

Comment: What does mean this: `=> any = {}` is it returned type?

Comment: This is assigning a value, with no type declaration: `let foo = () => {}`. This is declaring a variable and its type (but without assigning a value): `let foo: () => any`. This is both: `let foo: () => any = () => {}`. Makes sense? In other words, a colon `:` is followed by a type and an equality sign `=` is followed by a value.

Answer (score 6):

## The better approach

First, refactoring the function to take a single object param as in Nurbol's answer (which I upvoted) is IMO the better solution. Long argument lists of numbers are generally hard to use and prone to error.

## The literal answer

That said, if you really want to convert an object key's to an argument list for an existing function (for example say `do()` is beyond your control and cannot be refactored) like your question states you do have some options.

A naive approach would be to use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), which will convert an object's values to an array which can be [spread in as function arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
do(...Object.values(obj));
```

However the order of the values is not guaranteed (the same applies to all object key enumerations, like `for..in` or `forEach()`), so this isn't a good idea if the order of your function arguments matter, which it clearly does in your case.

To guarantee the correct param order you need to *explicitly define the order of keys* somehow. Here is an example of a generic function which takes an object and array of keys in order, then uses `array.reduce()` to produce the ordered argument list array:

```
function orderedArgs(obj: object, orderedKeys: string[]): any[] {
  return orderedKeys.reduce((args, key) => {
    args[orderedKeys.indexOf(key)] = obj[key as keyof object];
    return args;
  }, new Array(orderedKeys.length));
}

const argsOrder = ["classId", "schoolId", "pupilId", "teacherId", "roomId"];

const obj1 = { classId: 1, roomId: 3 }; 
doFn(...orderedArgs(obj1, argsOrder)); // passes: 1, undefined, undefined, undefined, 3

const obj2 = { schoolId: 5, pupilId: 4 };
doFn(...orderedArgs(obj2, argsOrder)); // passes: undefined, 5, 4, undefined, undefined
```

You can further abstract this with a helper function:

```
const callDo = (obj: object) => doFn(...orderedArgs(obj, ["classId", "schoolId", "pupilId", "teacherId", "roomId"]));

callDo({ classId: 1, roomId: 3 }); // passes: 1, undefined, undefined, undefined, 3

callDo({ schoolId: 5, pupilId: 4 }); // passes: undefined, 5, 4, undefined, undefined
```

Comment: I wish I'd have the time (and stamina & imagination) you have. Upvoted your answer as well.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if there any inbuilt functionality for this , but below code could work for you

```
function doSome(classId, 
    schoolId, 
    pupilId, 
    teacherId, 
    roomId)
    {
        console.log(classId, 
    schoolId, 
    pupilId, 
    teacherId, 
    roomId)
    }

    const Do = obj => {
        var classId , schoolId , pupilId , teacherId , roomId
        for(var k in obj){
           eval(k + "=" + obj[k])
        }
        doSome(classId , schoolId , pupilId , teacherId , roomId)
    }
```

Comment: Kinda brutal, looping over eval there